# social share icon and text are not refreshing in wordpress (either meta text or text in yeost SEO)

Tags: wordpress, facebook, sharing, yoast

I have a wordpress website with a survey that is shareable using social sharing plugins (I currently have mashshare as well as a hand coded button and both have the same issue). This survey is hardcoded in  PHP file so none of its contents can bee seen in the visual/text tabs of wordpress.

My problem is that when I change the share image and the text, both do not update when I share them to facebook. I can even delete the text and place a new one in and it will only show the original image and text and will not update.

i have a developer in india that claims he "fixed" this issue but he somehow got it to refresh one time. The problem still persists when I attempt to change the image or text.

Any idea how he got it to refresh OR how to fix it completely?

by the way, sharing on the rest of the site works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook cacheds the OG data, it is not meant to be changed the whole time and will even be locked after a while afaik. You can refresh it manually in the debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/